# Select dropdown shadow

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I am using the bootstrap select drop down and I want to put some  shadow on option list.

```
<select class="form-control nxreg-sign-up-country custom-form-control>
   <option>Please</option>
   <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
   <option value="AL">Albania</option>
   <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
   <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
```

Comment: There is not much you can do to style select elements

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662150/bootstrap-3-dropdown-select

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I style a <select> dropdown with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot style default dropdown from `<select>` tag, as the styling is handled by the user's OS.

Try using bootstrap select library https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/
It will replace the default dropdown with element which you can style.